# Recieving [main.o] error 2 in Qt creator

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to build one Qt project which I have downloaded from github. The .pro file is as below

```
QT       += core gui opengl widgets
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x000000`
TARGET = FiniteElements
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -lqwt

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/qwt/"\

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    FiniteElements.cpp \
    graph_plot.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    FiniteElements.h \
    graph_plot.h

#DEPENDPATH += include

#LIBS    +=  /home/hishamop/FEMprogs/QtFe
#INCLUDEPATH += include
```

When I tried to build it, I got the following error message

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
>   make: *** [mainwindow.o] Error 2
>   11:38:18: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project FiniteElements (kit: Desktop)
>   When executing step 'Make'

Comment: Could you please post all the text of error?

Comment: @demonplus. Qt creator  didn't show any further text other than this

Comment: Go to the "compiler output" tab on the bottom to see the actual message and post it.

Answer (score 0):

`INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/qwt/"\`

remove backslash at the end of the line (probably a typo?)